# Syncing Changing across two db tables

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

I have to create a UI application in which the user can search for a client/location combination and update it's location(or insert in case it doesn't exists). There can be several rows in table for a client depending on it's locations
 These changes need to be made in two different tables that reside on two separate databases.

```
CREATE TABLE ClientTab1
(
    Clientid INT
    , Location INT
    , Identifier INT IDENTITY
)

/* Separate db and this doesn't have an Identity column*/
CREATE TABLE ClientTab2
(
    Clientid INT
    , Location INT
)
```

Data:

```
ClientTab1:
101     9   1
101     21  2

ClientTab2:
101     9
101     21
```

Let's say that the user searches for:
Client 101, Location 9 
and updates this location to Location 3.
 Now, I can update the ClientTab1 using the identity column but there is no way for me to made the same changes in ClientTab2. 
 Please advice on an approach. 
 Please note that I can not link the two databases together. 
Thanks.

Comment: So you can't do: 

UPDATE ClientTab2 SET Location=3 WHERE ClientId=101; 

?

Comment: No, I want to update a single row in ClientTab2 (one that corresponds to Location = 9 but is now 3)

Comment: So, save the old value before updating the record, and do UPDATE ClientTab2 SET Location=3 WHERE ClientId=101 and Location=9;

Answer (score 0):

Save the old value for Location and use it in the update statement for your second update, eg.

```
UPDATE 
    ClientTab2 
SET 
    Location=3 
WHERE 
    ClientId=101 
    AND Location=9;
```